# Merging two branches without losing the code from root branch

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have two branches branch 1 and branch 2. Branch 1 has code like A,B,C and branch 2 has code as A,B,D. When i merge Branch 2 to 1, Branch 1 becomes A,B,D is there a way of merging where i can merge the two branches without loosing my code of one branch example merging branch 2 to 1 should return A,B,C,D.

**Branch 1**

cluster_name: 'development'

changes

num_tokens: 64

hinted_handoff_enabled: true

**Branch 2**

cluster_name: 'test'

changes

num_tokens: 16

**after merging** branch 2 to Branch it's returning below and losing `hinted_handoff_enabled: true`

cluster_name: 'test'

changes

num_tokens: 16

**What i want it to return**

cluster_name: 'test'

changes

num_tokens: 16

hinted_handoff_enabled: true

Comment: You started with naming the branches with numbers, then you name them with letters, then you continue with numbers.. Try to be consistent, otherwise it is hard to follow the idea.

Comment: You need to specify the contents of the latest common commit of these branches as well.

Comment: "Branch 1 has code like A,B,C and branch 2 has code as A,B,D." From your later example I see that the first line differs but you named it with the same letter 'A'. Please clarify your question. And don't forget to provide the contents of the latest common commit.

Comment: They share a common history? I would suppose so, right? And then did you rename C to D (or viceversa) into one of the branches?